# How to update Mercurial on the Mac to use CAC Authentication

Tags: python, mercurial

Anyone have an idea as to how to update Mecurial on the Mac to use CAC Authentication?

I have a supplied version on my work PC but would like to use the Mac for all my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install additional packages or newer versions on MacOS using third party packages from e.g. [macports](https://www.macports.org/) or [homebrew](https://brew.sh). I prefer macports. Both provide a good documentation on how to start

EDIT:
Have you checked this [page](https://web.archive.org/web/20211124202752/http://mercurial.berkwood.com/)?

Second Edit:
Might be mercurial needs [python 2.7](https://www.python.org/getit/)

So no need in this case for macports or homebrew

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping to get away with a quick fix...lol
I'm digging into MacPorts now.

Comment: Yes, was hoping there was a solution that I could just download and install, but it's obvious that I'll need to make some changes to mercurial on my end.